# warning output stream supposed to be a string but is an array

Tags: powershell

I try to get an output from a warning output-stream and put the result in a hashtable and convert it later to json, the warning supposed to be a string, single line (and it is!), but when I create a hashtable using the value of the stream I'll get an array with additional infos. I'd like to get rid of it interested only in the warning message.
The code:

```
$res = $newSQLInstallation.InstallSQLServer() 3> warning.txt 
$err = get-content warning.txt # the value here is: [11:53:35][Invoke-DbaAdvancedInstall] Installation failed with exit code -2068643838. Expand 'ExitMessage' and 'Log' "
...
    $table = @{
    retvalue = @{
        result = ""
        definition = "SQL Server Installation: $($newSQLInstallation.ServerName)"
        }
    }

if($err)
{
    $table.retvalue.result = $err
    throw $table
} 
else
{
    $table.retvalue.result = "Success"    
}   
return $table | ConvertTo-Json
```

but I get this output:

```
{
"retvalue": {
"definition": "SQL Server Installation: sqlserver1",
"result": {
  "Context": null,
  "Filename": "InputStream",
  "IgnoreCase": true,
  "Line": "[11:53:35][Invoke-DbaAdvancedInstall] Installation failed with exit code -2068643838. Expand 'ExitMessage' and 'Log' ",
  "LineNumber": 1,
  "Matches": "failed",
  "Path": "InputStream",
  "Pattern": "failed"
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any array in your code.  Are you asking how you get the message without the timestamp/trace info?

Comment: 1. yes, I just want the string "....failed....." and put this string in my jagged hasttable: result="...error....", no additional values needed.
2. you're right, it's not an array, it looks like a hashtable: context:null, filename="inputstream" and so on

Comment: `$Table.retvalue.result.Pattern` ?

Comment: no, I need the value from the variable $err to place it into the variable $table.retvalue.result, not the another way round.

Comment: What does `$err.GetType()` return? Maybe you need `$table.retvalue.result = $err[3]` or `$table.retvalue.result = ($err[3] -split  ': ')[-1]` if $err is an array or `$err['Line']` if it's a hashtable.

Comment: Keith: strangely $err.GetType() it's a system.string